# How to process my own syntax concluding tags and attributes?

Tags: php, syntax, attributes

This my seem to be little odd but i want to make my own syntax for application other than xml or any other standard.

So what i want to do is something like this:

```
    [tag atr=|value| atr=|value value value|] 
    [tag atr=|value| atr=|value value value|] 
    [tag atr=|value| atr=|value value value|]
```

and then loop trough and put atr in variables or array

```
    $tag1 = Array ( [atr] => value [atr] => value )
    $tag2 = Array ( [atr] => value [atr] => value )
    $tag3 = Array ( [atr] => value [atr] => value )
```

I figured out that i need to find a string between [ and ]. put those stings into an array loop trough and then see what tag is used to trigger specific action and send te values of the attributes along with that action.

if any one has some code or tips it would be useful. Sorry for reinventing the wheel but i rely need this.

Comment: It is a bit hard to comprehend your question. Is the syntax you use literal? If so, why did you skip the , in the associative array?

Comment: Why would you write your own? I would suggest to look at yaml or plain csv.

Comment: I want to make my own because it will be used in a variation of other standards as .cfg or .xml so it has to be unique in its own way, so it does not mess up with the .cfg or .xml when processed. a example from word file here [link](http://217.121.76.24:8888/test/syntax/eigen%20syntax.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making my own syntax or dom I use XML with my own preserved tags witch do not occur in these day's standards. This way I can process the tags I made without intervention of similar tags form the string.

The XML can be processed using php functions such as simplexml_load_string. This functions puts the XML in an object and makes it a huge array witch i can handle with for each loops in PHP.